# Django Wagtail template - if statement not working

Tags: html, django, if-statement, templates, wagtail

Hi hopefully this is a simple fix. I'm still fairly new to Django/Wagtail and would appreciate any help. My goal is to better format my form fields by filtering with the field.label_tag value.

I know for a fact the value of field.label_tag is as expected, but still no luck after confirming the output in the template and trying a few variations on the if statement.

```
      {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
            {% if field.label_tag|stringformat:"s" == "Email Address" %}
              <strong>field.label_tag</strong> 
            {% endif %}
            {% if field.label_tag|stringformat:"s" == "Message" %}
              {% render_field field class+="form-control" placeholder+="Message" id+="message" %}
            {% endif %}
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>  
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You probably want to do `if field.label|stringformat:"s"  == "Email Address"`

Comment: `field.label_tag` renders the whole tag html out `<label for="id_email">Email address:</label>`, take a look of this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields

Comment: @MohitC - Thank you very much, field.label was the solution here.

Comment: @minglyu - I appreciate the explanation and link. Previously I was trying to find some reference material for this concept but had no luck.

Comment: @zephyr19, yw posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to string match with label of field, you can do

```
if field.label|stringformat:"s" == "Email Address"
```